# External HDD (Apple_HFS) not recognised by Finder under Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, hard-drive, macos, external-disk

my external HDD (used for TM backups and some other stuff) suddenly stopped working with my MBP 2017 (Sierra 10.12.6). I can see it only through the Terminal (see screenshot 1)

[image: Screenshot 1]

DiskUtility won't load when this particular HDD is plugged. I have also tried several diskutil command lines:

verifyVolume & repairVolume
[image: Screenshot 2]

verifyDisk
[image: Screenshot 3]

repairDisk
[image: Screenshot 4]

Did not perform the last one, cause I really don't want to lose my data.
*Tested on two Windows* machines with Apple_HFS driver. **Driver was found and data are just fine and readable.**

Someone with an idea how to fix this without losing data? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If you don't want to lose the data, why aren't you backing it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I gave it another try in Safe-Mode and voila - my external HDD was visible, so I made "First-Aid" and did a reboot into normal mode back again. Everything seems to be fine now.